# Uncaught ReferenceError: $this is not defined ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm very new in javascript and ajax. i want to make dynamic select option list like this.

[image]

but there is error like this when i try to compile using google chrome developer (press F12).

[image]

here is my script :

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-lg-6">
                <h1 class="text-center">Ajax & Codeigniter Select Box Dependent</h1>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="country">Country</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
                        <option value="">Select Country</option>
                        <?php foreach ($countries as $country) : ?> 
                            <option value="<?php echo $country->country_id; ?>"><?php echo $country->country_name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pwd">Province:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="province" id="province" disabled="">
                        <option value="">Select Province</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#country').on('change',function(){
                var country_id = $($this).val();
                if(country_id == '')
                {
                    $('#province').prop('disabled',true);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#province').prop('disabled',false);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

if you know what wrong with my code, please help me.
Thanks

Comment: `var country_id = $(this).val();`

Comment: What do you not understand about the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo, most probably:

```
$('#country').on('change',function(){
    var country_id = $($this).val();
    //                 ^ Remove this $ sign
    ...
})
```

Replace `$($this)` with `$(this)`, because you didn't define `$this`. `this` (without `$`) is the context.

---

Also, as an improvement, you can remove the `if` and the repetitive code by doing:

```
$('#country').on('change',function(){
  var country_id = $(this).val();
  $('#province').prop('disabled', country_id == '');
});
```

Furthermore, you can do directly:

```
$('#country').on('change',function(){
  $('#province').prop('disabled', this.value == '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
 var country_id = $($this).val();
```

to

```
 var country_id = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#country').on('change', function () {
                        var country_id = $(this).val();
                        if (country_id == '') {
                            $('#province').prop('disabled', true);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#province').prop('disabled', false);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```